# How to lint a gemspec file

Tags: ruby, rubygems, gemspecs

When building new gems I like to run the command `gem build app.gemspec` instead of `rake build` because I get extra warnings, kind of *lint* for my gem specification.

However both commands have the problem that they actually generate in gem file and that is something that I never want, since I use my gems by referencing either their repository or path from other projects inside the **Gemfile** of those other projects.

Is there a way to *lint* / *test* my gemspec files like `gem build` does without actually generating the final gem? `gem build` does not support the `--dry-run` command

Answer (score 2):

Is 'gem check' what you are looking for? There are a variety of options, including --dry-run

http://guides.rubygems.org/command-reference/#gem-check

Comment: I does not seem the solution I am looking for. That is for checking an existing gem, while I am trying to check a gemspec without generating the gem file. However it seems a good addition to my lint task.